# Reading CSV in Pandas and Getting Output in the Required Format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to `pandas`. I'm reading a `csv` file and trying to get output as a `dictionary`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('source.csv')
my_projects = ['WORLD', 'P&G', 'AVR', 'ABCD', 'Channel', 'Migration']
filtered_projects = df[(df['area'] == 'MY PROJECTS') & (df['name'].isin(my_projects))]
filtered_projects['count'] = 1
total_of_each_error = filtered_projects.groupby(['month','name','errors']).sum().reset_index()
total_of_each_error['month'] = pd.to_datetime(total_of_each_error['month']).dt.strftime('%B')
```

The list of things I'm trying to count: `['Big', 'Small', 'Monitoring', 'Improvement']`

The `total_of_each_error` data frame has:

```
    month        name       errors     count
0   February     ABCD        Big         1
1   February     ABCD      Monitoring    3
2   February     WORLD     Small         1
3   February     Channel    Big          2
4   February     Channel   Small         1
5   February     Channel  Monitoring     1
6   February     AVR      Monitoring     1
7   April       WORLD     Monitoring     2
8   May         Migration    Big         1
9   May         Migration Monitoring     2
10  June        P&G       Small          1
11  June        P&G       Monitoring     1
12  June        ABCD      Monitoring     1
13  June        WORLD    Improvement     1
14  July        P&G      Monitoring      1
15  July        ABCD         Small       1
16  July        ABCD     Monitoring      1
```

If a month doesn't have a particular error, a zero should be filled in. The output I'm trying to get is this `dictionary`:

```
data = {'WORLD': {'categories': ['February', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                'series': [{
                    'name': 'Big Issue',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # Number of Bigs in those months
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Small Issue',
                    'data': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # Number of Smalls in those months
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Monitoring',
                    'data': [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]  # Number of Monitorings in those months
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Improvement',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]  # Number of Improvements in those months
                    }]
                },
        'P&G': {'categories': ['February', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                'series': [{
                    'name': 'Big Issue',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Small Issue',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Monitoring',
                    'data': [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
                    }, {
                    'name': 'Improvement',
                    'data': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
                    }]
                }      

    }
```

Expected output shown above is for `WORLD` and `P&G` only. The dictionary would be complete with the rest of the elements in `my_projects`. The order of months and data should be preserved.

**Edit**: Changed a wrong value in `name`

Answer (score 0):

Would sorting and modifying your dataframe into the correct format (use `df.groupby` and `.unstack()`) then using the `to_dict()` method on your dataframe get the results you want. Example below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data ={'Month': ['Jan','Feb']*5,
           'Issue': ['Big Issue','Monitoring']*5,
           'value': np.arange(30,40)})

df.groupby(['Month','Issue']).count().unstack()
df.to_dict()

    df.to_dict()
```